# Obtaining OAuth2AccessToken via @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") vs OAuth2AuthorizedClientService

Tags: spring, azure, spring-security, oauth-2.0

**The problem**

I tried two different options to obtain an access token for an authenticated user. They both give me the access token and I can proceed further. However, I face the problem when the token expires (provided I've been using the app all the time). The first option of obtaining the token works well, just as expected, I get a new token after the old one expires, but I can't use it in an interceptor or filter. I have many services where I need to obtain the access token and verify it, so I want to put the solution in a library in a filter and reuse it in all the services.

The second option, allows me to use it in an interceptor, but it keeps giving me the old access token even after it's expired.

Why does this happen? Did anyone run into this problem and is there a solution to this?

**First Option**

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
   return authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
}
```

**Second Option**

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        var authentication = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        var authorizedClient = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient("azure", authentication.getName());

        servletRequest.setAttribute("access-token", authorizedClient.getAccessToken());
        
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you managed to solve it?